# I want to refer to one of the database tables in one of the files in the views folder in my project

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to refer to one of the database tables in one of the files in the views folder in my project
How can I do this?
For example:
Display the value of a column named sub, which is located in the configs table in my database

Notice that I know that html is not a server-side language; I just want to display my information, not edit it

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the name of the columns of your table?

Comment: No, I want to display the value of that column

Comment: Your question is not clear! If you want a column value just get that table via model and echo the column value e.g `$object = YourModel::find(1);` and pass the object to your view and print it there.

Comment: Don't have any code for html?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may access it via the DB facade.

```
$column =  DB::table('configs')->pluck('sub');
```

If you have a `Config` model, you can get  it like this:

```
$config = Config::find(1);
$config->sub;
```

You may look at the docs here too:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the MVC principle, you can use an [Eloquent Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) to map database information, [Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers) to send the model data to your view and [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade) to display that data in your view.

Just a basic example:

`Config.php` (Model inside the `App` folder):

```
class Config extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model, only needs to be defined 
     * if your table name isn't a plural of your model name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'configs';
}
```

`HomeController` (Controller in `App\Http\Controllers`)

```
use App\Config;
...

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $configs = Config::all();

        return view('index', ['configs' => $configs]);
    }
}
```

`index.blade.php` (View inside `resources/views`)

```
@foreach ($configs as $config)
    {{ $config->sub }} // This prints the value of the sub column for every row in the configs table
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want displaying data you just make an echo
for single element do this

```
{{ $mode->colum_name }}
```

if you have more than one element you have yo make like this

```
@foreach($models as $model)
    {{$model->column_name}}
@endforeach
```